# .Net 3.5: Where could I find Microsoft Interactive chart control?

Tags: charts

Take a look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRnUAwUFIgY
Where could I find that interface from the first minute?

Answer (score 0):

[The controls are here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en).
[The samples are here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591).

Comment: Found it:   http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  Edited.